# Javascript - few intervals in right order

Tags: javascript, setinterval

In my code I have three intervals which should be executed random times one after the another.

```
    var times =  Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 2);
    var turn = 0;
    var schemaInterval1 = setInterval(function(){
        console.log('first');
        turn++;
        if(turn == times)
        {   
            times =  Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 2);
            turn = 0;
            clearInterval(schemaInterval1);
        }
    },1000);
    var schemaInterval2 = setInterval(function(){
        console.log('second');
        turn++;
        if(turn == times)
        {   
            times =  Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 2);
            turn = 0;
            clearInterval(schemaInterval2);
        }
    },1000);
        var schemaInterval3 = setInterval(function(){
        console.log('third');
        turn++;
        if(turn == times)
        {   
            times =  Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 2);
            turn = 0;
            clearInterval(schemaInterval3);
        }
    },1000);
```

After each execution of the code within interval, I add 1 to the turn value. When turn and times values are equal I reset both of them. Leave currently working interval and skip to another one. But unfortunately they don't work in correct order and in my console I get that message:

```
 first
 second
 third
 first
 second
 first
 (4)second
```

How can I rewrite my code to put those intervals in proper order and don't allow others work until first finish it's task?

Comment: Put the whole code in one interval?

Answer (score 0):

You start your intervals all at the same time. If you want to run them in series, you have to start one when you clear the previous one.
This code should do what you are looking for:

```js
var times =  Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 2);
var turn = 0;
var intervalNumber = 1;
var intervalTime = 1000;
var numberOfIntervals = 3;
function instantiateInterval() {
  if (intervalNumber <= numberOfIntervals) {
    console.log('Timer number: ' + intervalNumber);
    var interval = setInterval(function() {
      turn++;
      if(turn === times) {   
        times =  Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 2);
        turn = 0;
        clearInterval(interval);
        instantiateInterval();
      }
    }, intervalTime);
    intervalNumber++;
  }
}
instantiateInterval();
```